# Creating a piano in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js, piano

I am creating a piano using p5.js. I need help with the color change. When a user presses a key, I want the key to flash a quick color change to let them know that they pressed the key.

In my code, the color does change when you click on the first key, however, when I click a little bit outside the first key, the first key still changes color.

Is my distance a little off? Or is there a more effective way to do this?

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(990, 600);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  fill(255);
  rect(0, 300, 70, 400);
  rect(70, 300, 70, 400);
  rect(140, 300, 70, 400);
  rect(210, 300, 70, 400);
  rect(280, 300, 70, 400);
  rect(350, 300, 70, 400);
  rect(420, 300, 70, 400);
  rect(490, 300, 70, 400);
  rect(560, 300, 70, 400);
  rect(630, 300, 70, 400);
  rect(700, 300, 70, 400);
  rect(770, 300, 70, 400);
  rect(840, 300, 70, 400);
  rect(910, 300, 70, 400);
  fill(0);
  rect(50, 300, 38, 180);
  rect(120, 300, 38, 180);
  rect(260, 300, 38, 180);
  rect(330, 300, 38, 180);
  rect(400, 300, 38, 180);
  rect(540, 300, 38, 180);
  rect(610, 300, 38, 180);
  rect(750, 300, 38, 180);
  rect(820, 300, 38, 180);
  rect(890, 300, 38, 180);
  text("mouse x: "+mouseX+" mouse y:"+mouseY, width/2,height-30);
 }

function mousePressed() {
  cursor(HAND);

}

function mouseReleased() {
    cursor(ARROW);

let d = dist(mouseX, mouseY, 0, 300);
  if (d < 300) {
    fill(0);
    rect(0, 300, 70, 400);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking whether the mouse position is withing 300 pixels of the point 0,300. This sets up a **circle** with a center of 0,300 and a radius of 300. Try drawing that in your scene to see where your clickable area is.

Your keys are rectangles, so you should be using point-**rectangle intersection** to check whether the mouse is inside a particular key. Google is your friend here, but basically you want to check whether `mouseX` is between the left and right edges, and `mouseY` is between the top and bottom edges.

Finally, note that you're only ever showing the "flash" for a single frame. I personally can't even see it. You probably want to show the flash for longer, using the `millis()` function or the `frameCount` variable for timing. (Again, Google is your friend!)

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) is a tutorial on collision detection, including point-rectangle intersection. It's for Processing, but the ideas are the same in P5.js.